# Size limitations of Tkinter grid manager

Tags: python, performance, grid, tkinter

I'm writing a Python application to parse a list of binary files, aggregate statistics on the data in them, and output results. I can easily output these results as a .tsv file, but this program is being written for the convenience of my coworkers, so I'm trying to have it display the results in a new window to sometimes prevent having to open the file in Excel. Right now I'm basically embedding a Tkinter frame in a scrolled canvas and gridding smaller frames containing labels of the data into the frame. (The smaller frames seem to be necessary to get all the borders to line up with the gridlines; otherwise they are shrinkwrapped to fit the labels)

This approach works with upwards of a hundred columns and maybe ten rows. But when I start increasing the number of rows to the hundreds, I start encountering odd problems. The program might become unresponsive, the new window might not display, and all the labels, rather than being drawn in the grid, are all placed in the top left corner of my screen. Since this appears to be a scale-related problem, I'm wondering if I'm simply overwhelming the grid manager with tens of thousands of elements to place. So I have two questions: 1) Could I be running into such limitations, or is the problem elsewhere, and 2) Is there a better way to implement an Excel-like table display in Tkinter that steers clear of these problems?

Comment: Using frames with labels in them for each cell? I just did this: `label.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky=W)`, and made the label have the same background color as the table's frame.

Comment: I was using frame borders to more clearly delineate between grid cells. I suppose it's worth a shot to see if going without improve performance.

Comment: If you want to see simple solid lines around the grid cells, just color the background frame black, then arrange for a one pixel border between each row and column. This lets you do away with the separate frame for each cell and gives a nice hairline separation because the background will "peek through" the gaps between each cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a test program to display the data two ways, once using a frame and grid and once drawing text directly on the canvas.

Using the frame+grid technique, the performance of 100 rows times 10 columns was quite acceptable. When I bumped that up to 200 rows the performance was more than 2x worse, and by the time I got to 300 rows, performance was unusable. And by that I mean, it took dozens of seconds for the initial display. Once the window appeared, however, the performance was acceptable.

Drawing text items directly on the canvas, performance was *considerably* better. I could display 300 rows by 10 columns and the initial display was almost instantaneous. Performance was still acceptable when I had 1000 rows with 100 columns, taking maybe 2-3 seconds to start up.

So, for a large number of cells you're better off drawing them directly on the canvas. This means you'll need to calculate the height of a row yourself, and also do a little math for the columns -- either use fixed width columns or keep track of the widest and then adjust the coordinates accordingly.

Comment: Sounds promising. How do I find the width of the widest column? (i.e. get the total width a label needs; Tkinter seems to have about three different width get methods)

Comment: @dpitch40: The easiest way is to compute the bounding box of each item, and from that get the actual width. Then, remember the widest item for each column. When you create the items, give each one a tag based on the column (eg: "col0", "col1", etc). Then, you can use the `move` method of the canvas to move all items in each column at once (eg: `canvas.move("col0", xoffset)`). You then just need to compute an appropriate offset for each column with a little math based on the widest item in each column. Doing this, I was able to display 10,000 rows of 10 columns in about 8 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The grid geometry manager runs into problems as things get larger; it's not designed for dealing with very large numbers of subwindows (i.e., anything where you'd want to scale beyond what you can comfortably have without scrolling). Instead, you're looking for [TkTable](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/TkTable). That can scale up to handling very large tabular data.

Comment: This application isn't just for me. If I manage to install TkTable and package the application in a binary, will other users need Cygwin and all its dependencies to run it?

Comment: It's not important that the grid be interactive, it's just a way of previewing results. If I draw the cells directly onto the canvas using its drawing tools, will I still have these problems?

Comment: There's definitely a tipping point with the grid geometry manager. I can write a test program with 1000 cells (100 rows, 10 columns) and the performance is quite acceptable. When I bump that up to 300 rows it takes *considerably*  longer than 3x for the window to initially display. However, once it displays, it displays and performs quite well.